# Why friend function without argument is not working?

Tags: c++, class, friend-function

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    class complex{
        private:
        int x;
    
        public:
        friend void fun(void);
    };
    
    void fun(void)
    {
        cout<<"outside "<<endl;
    }
    int main()
    {
        complex c1;
        c1.fun();
        return 0;
    }
```

why I'm getting the following error which says that 'class complex' has no member named 'fun' in VS code

```
36_friend_function.cpp: In function 'int main()':
36_friend_function.cpp:19:8: error: 'class complex' has no member named 'fun'
     c1.fun();
        ^~~
```

Comment: Please explain your goal not just the symptom you stumble over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fun` is a friend of complex, which means it is allowed to use internals of that object. It is not part of the object though, so you can not call it via the object.

You must call `fun`just like any other function, which it is.

Example:

```
void fun(complex &c)
{
    // fun is a friend so it can access private member x.
    cout << "outside " << c.x << endl;
}

int main()
{
    complex c1;
    fun(c1);
    return 0;
}
```